# Windows 10 Lock Screen controls grayed out

Tags: windows-10, group-policy, lock-screen

My lock screen controls are grayed out, and there is a banner at the
top saying "Some of these settings are hidden or locked by your
organization".

As per the instructions at
https://techdows.com/2015/09/fix-windows-10-lock-screen-some-settings-are-managed-by-your-organization.html,
I used the Group Policy Editor (I needed to open it as Administrator)
and navigated to:

```
Computer Configuration
  > Administrative Templates
  > Control Panel
  > Personalization
```

I'm supposed to set `Do not display the lock screen` to `Enabled`, but it
is already set that way.

**Why else would the Lock Screen control be grayed out?**

Please note that I have no problem with the Lock Screen.  I was simply
following the advice at
https://www.pcworld.com/article/3039827/7-ways-windows-10-pushes-ads-at-you-and-how-to-stop-them.html
to remove ads from my new Windows 10 Pro laptop.

Comment: Change all the settings in that section to "Not Configured", exit, restart and test

Comment: A quick way to lock the screen is to use Windows key + L, does that work?

Comment: "I'm supposed to set Do not display the lock screen to Enabled, but it is already set that way."  Should be set to disabled.

Comment: **John:** I'm reluctant to change a lot of things indiscriminately.  **Moab:** I'm not trying to lock the screen, I'm just following the mentioned page for avoiding ads. You're almost right about setting `Do not display the lock screen` setting.  I misread the instructions.  It's supposed to set to `Not configured`.  Would you be so kind as to post that as the answer? Thanks!

Comment: Funny, this.  It turns out that I don't want the `Not configured` setting. It doesn't get rid of the ads when I click on Start. In fact, I vaguely recall switching this setting to `Enabled` to prevent display of the clock time, as per findings on the internet.